# Determine if DescribeFieldResult is writeable by anyone not current user

Tags: describefieldresult

I'm trying to build a list of fields for an object in Apex that are writeable by any user. There are methods `isCreateable()` and `isUpdatable()` but those return results based on the current user. Is there any way to get the results if the field is createable or updatable by any user? I'm trying to build a list of fields excluding system fields like SystemModStamp. My fallback is to exclude them explicitly but was curious if there's a better way.

Here's the list of methods I was perusing for a better alternative:
https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_fields_describe.htm

Answer (score 0):

It would seem you'd definitely want to know `isPermissionable()` as well as `isNamePointing()`. The former tells you whether field level permissions can be set for the field. If they can't, then its unlikely that another user would have permission to access fields that the current user doesn't. That assumes the current user has access to the object. Recognize that simply having object level access will be critical if the OWD for the object is set to Private.

The latter of the two would tell you if the field is a child of something else or related to an entirely different object. If it is, you may want to know whether `isWriteRequiresMasterRead()` is true, and possibly the value of `getReferenceTargetField()`.

Those would be the ones that would seem to be of the most value to look at from what I can see if you're looking to determine access for users other than the current user; something that appears to me as though its going to be rather complex and very challenging to do.